# mvc3 submit button not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

There is a Html.BeginForm contains Ajax.BeginForm and out side the Ajax.BeginForm there is one
submit button. But this submit button not working. If I take submit button before Ajax.BeginForm
it's working fine. Submit button inside the Ajax.BeginForm is also working fine. My question is that
why submit button is not working if I take submit button after the Ajax.BeginForm;
Thanks in advance.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AssignTestGet", "Test"))
{

   using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestPreviewTemplate", "Test", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "template" }))
    {
        <button type="submit" id="questionId" name="questionId" value="@ViewBag.id" class="submit" style="margin-left:45px;margin-top:-15px;"></button>
        <input type="hidden" id="templateId"value="@ViewBag.id" name="templateId" class="tr"/>
    }
    <div id="template">
    @Html.Partial("_testTemplate", Model)
    </div>


    <input type="submit" value="submit" />  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

HTML do not support one form between another. It is the violation of HTML rule. So, When Parsing then it only parse Outer form not the inner Form and so the outer submit button do not work.

You can use two form Differently giving different Id.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AssignTestGet", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id ="OuterForm" }))
 {
    <div id="template">

    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="mymyb" />  
}


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestPreviewTemplate", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin="MyMy()", UpdateTargetId = "template" }, new { @id="innerForm"}))
{
    <input type="submit" value="submit Inner" id="mymyba" />  
}
```